# extract item from each pair in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to access the value stored after 'a' for each pair in this dictionary. For some reason I get the following error 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'. I am not sure why this is happening here, so any advice is welcome. thank you!

```
dic = dict({'out': [{'a': '1', 'v': '10'}, {'a':'2', 'v': '20'}]})
```

code

```
for i in dic.keys(): print (dic[i]['a'])
```

expected output

```
1, 2
```

Comment: You show us the error and that's good. But you haven't shown us your code. Please [edit] and add it.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp whoops thank you for pointing that out! added now

Answer (score 1):

it is because `out` is the only key of `dic`, and have `dic['out']` is a list of dicts. So you'd want to iterate over that list, and for each item of this list (which is a dict) you can access the `'a'` key. Something like

```
for k in dic.keys(): # iterate dic
    for d in dic[k]: # iterate the list, items are dicts
        print(d['a']) # fetch 'a' key of each dictionary in the list
```